# Registered or not HTML custom URL scheme detection

Tags: javascript, html

In my site I have a custom URL which triggers an installed app, for example

```
<a href="customapp:12345">Click</a>
```

If my Windows app has registered the URL scheme, Chrome prompts the user to open it.

The question is, if the app is not registered, is there a way for me to find it and prompt the user to install it?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: only as a "download then open" type of situation. You cannot launch OS processes from within the browser.

Comment: I'm not looking to launch it, I want ot know if the scheme is registered or not.

Comment: How do you expect to "know if the scheme is registered or not" if the scheme registration is an OS level feature? Perhaps by using (launching) an OS level tool of some sort. Hmmmm, still cannot launch an OS level tool from inside the browser.

Comment: I don't know, that's why I'm asking, if there's a Javascript feature that would help.

Comment: There is no JavaScript feature in the browser that will allow that. (cannot launch an OS level tool). Answer is still no.

Comment: The only "solution" I can see is to tell the user that the link will fail unless they install the app first, linking to the download. But I guess that's exactly what you want to avoid?

Comment: I never used that but I guess that when clicked and app opens, window triggers blur. Its not accurate but atleast something..

Answer (score 0):

I found that `window.onblur` seems to be called if you attempt to open a scheme link and the handler is installed. This is because it either opens the registered app or opens a box asking if you want to open the app, both of which take the focus. If it's not installed the focus stays where it was.

This worked for me on Windows 10/Chrome, macOS/Chrome, android/Chrome, android/Silk & Linux/Firefox.

call `tryScheme("yourScheme://blahblah", function() { <it's not installed code> })`

```
var blurred = false;

window.onblur = function() {
    blurred = true;
}

function tryScheme(url, fallbackFunction) {    
    blurred = false;       

    document.location = url;

    // If we haven't lost focus in a fairly short time, call it as not installed.
    setTimeout(function(){
        if (blurred === true) {
            console.log("Focus away from page - the scheme's probably installed");               
            return;
        }
        
        console.log("Still on page - the scheme's probably not installed");                           
        fallbackFunction();
    }, 1000);
}
```